# This pointer is 0xfffffffc, potential causes?

Tags: c++, memory, gdb, this-pointer

I'm compiling the Crypto++ library at `-O3`. According to Undefined Behavior Sanitizer (UBsan) and Address Sanitizer (Asan), its OK. The program runs fine at `-O2` (and `-O3` on many platforms).

Its also OK according to Valgrind under `-O2`. At `-O3`, Valgrind dies with *"Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind does not understand"*. I'm fairly certain that's because of SSE4 instructions and vectorizations at `-O3`.

However, I'm catching a crash on some platforms with `-O3`. This particular machine is Fedora 22 i686, and its has GCC 5.2.1. The frame in question shows `this=0xfffffffc`:

```gdb
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0807be29 in CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_IntegerBased::GetEncodedElementSize
    (this=0xfffffffc, reversible=0x1) at gfpcrypt.h:55
55      unsigned int GetEncodedElementSize(bool reversible) const {return GetModulus().ByteCount();}
```

The best I can tell, there's nothing located around that address:

```gdb
(gdb) info shared
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0xb7fdd860  0xb7ff6b30  Yes (*)     /lib/ld-linux.so.2
0xb7eb63d0  0xb7f7a344  Yes (*)     /lib/libstdc++.so.6
0xb7e005f0  0xb7e32bd8  Yes (*)     /lib/libm.so.6
0xb7951060  0xb7980cc4  Yes (*)     /lib/libubsan.so.0
0xb7932090  0xb7948001  Yes (*)     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
0xb7916840  0xb79238d1  Yes (*)     /lib/libpthread.so.0
0xb775d3f0  0xb78a0b6b  Yes (*)     /lib/libc.so.6
0xb7741a90  0xb7742a31  Yes (*)     /lib/libdl.so.2
```

I've seen `this=0x00000000` *if* a static class object declared in one translation unit is used in another translation unit before initialization is complete. But I don't recall seeing `0xfffffffc` in the past.

What are some potential reasons for `this=0xfffffffc`? Or how can I troubleshoot it further?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a 32 bits machine `0xfffffffc` is `((int*)nullptr)-1`. So perhaps you are taking the previous element of a nil pointer (e.g. wrongly using some reverse iterator, etc etc...)

Use the `bt` or `backtrace` command of `gdb` to understand what has happened. I guess that the trouble is in the caller (or its caller, etc...)

Try also some other compiler (e.g. some older version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and several versions of [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)....). You could have some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) that your other tools did not detect as such. You need to understand if the bug is inside Crypto++ (or perhaps, but very unlikely, it is inside GCC itself; then report a bug on [GCC bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/)....). If you suspect the compiler, pass `-S -fverbose-asm -fdump-tree-all -O3` to `g++` to understand what GCC is doing.... (this will dump hundreds of files, including the generated `.s` assembler code).

Ask also on [crypto++ lists](http://www.cryptopp.com/#lists); perhaps report the bug on Crypto++ bug tracker. Test with other versions or snapshot of that library

BTW, I'm not sure that `-fsanitize=undefined` or `-fsanitize=address` should be used with `-O3`; I guess that they are more suitable with `-O0 -g` or `-Og -g`

Comment: Yes, this is a 32-bit machine (x86_64 is fine, btw). Asking on the mailing list probably won't help. Filing a bug report probably won't help.

Comment: It should help. You have found a bug (probably in Crypto++ itself, possibly in GCC) and you should report it. It might not help immediately (some bugs take months to be corrected). And I believe that when finding a possible bug in any free software, reporting it is a moral duty.

Comment: It won't help because I'm the guy ... Wei Dai (who wrote the library) is busy with other things, so a handful of us are maintaining and adding features.

Comment: @jww FWIW, GCC-5.2 has just been released *an hour ago*. I don't know what you are using on Fedora, but an official release of GCC-5.2.1 does not appear to exist.